# ORA-24805:LOB type mismatch

Tags: sql, oracle, dbms-crypto

Let there be table `A(text_1 varchar2(4000 CHAR), text_2 varchar(4000 CHAR))`
And here is the select for this:

```
SELECT sys.dbms_crypto.hash(empty_clob() || text_1 || text_2, 2)  from A;
```

I am getting error 24805. I am expecting casting `text_1` and `text_2` to  `CLOB` , and connecting to each other. After that I need to get hash_code using function below. This code will also be part of PL/SQL block ( part of insert statement in function).
If I will use this:

```
SELECT sys.dbms_crypto.hash(to_clob('') || text_1 || text_2, 2)  from A;
```

Everything is ok now. So, what was the problem?

```
 create table A(text_1 varchar2(4000 CHAR), text_2 varchar2(4000 CHAR));
 insert into A(text_1,text_2)values ('test1','test2');
 commit;
```

Here is an example of creating data for A.

Comment: Could you provide some example data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [TO_CLOB](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/TO_CLOB-character.html#GUID-82E2FAD3-B0C8-4A06-A882-26211EE0524C) for concatenate your char based columns. Then use [CONCAT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm) which seems can work with CLOB. Try below.

```
SELECT DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH(CONCAT(TO_CLOB (TEXT_1) , TO_CLOB (TEXT_2)), 2)  FROM A;
```

Comment: This is one of the better approach. Upvoting you

Comment: I appreciate it @JimMacaulay

Answer (score 1):

Please try below query,

```
SELECT sys.dbms_crypto.hash(to_clob(text_1 || text_2), 2)  from A;
```

Comment: Yes, I know that it is the best way, but in pl/sql block I will have an error if text_1, text_2 contain 4000 CHARS, cause result of string concatenation is too long.

Comment: I edited my code would you try mine? @СтаниславКитаев